# Issues with ActionListener (Java)

Tags: swing

I am trying to implement action listener on two buttons in JFrame, but the issue is one of the two button is performing both the functions; but i've not configured it to do so. Please find the sample code:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyChangingCirlce implements ActionListener{
JButton colorButton, labelButton;
JLabel myLabel;
MyDrawPanel mdp;
JFrame frame;
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    MyChangingCirlce mcc = new MyChangingCirlce();
    mcc.createFrame();
   } 

  public void createFrame()
  {
frame = new JFrame();
colorButton = new JButton("Changing Colors");
labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
myLabel = new JLabel("BA");
mdp = new MyDrawPanel();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mdp);   
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,colorButton); 
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,labelButton);  
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,myLabel);
colorButton.addActionListener(this);
labelButton.addActionListener(this);    
frame.setSize(300,300);
frame.setVisible(true);

  } // end of createFrame Method


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if(e.getSource()== colorButton)
{
frame.repaint();        
}
else
{
myLabel.setText("AB");
}

}   //end of interface method...
```

}

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue= (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval(20,70,100,100);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You think the button triggers both the `if` and `else` statement but that is not the case. If you would adjust your code in the following way:

- add a `setColor`, `changeColor` or something similar to your `MyDrawPanel` class
- adjust the `MyDrawPanel#paintComponent` method to use a fixed color instead of a random color, and only adjust the color through the method created in the first step
- your color change button should use the method created in the first step to adjust the color of the `MyDrawPanel`

The thing is that `paintComponent` can be called by Swing itself. It is not only called when you call `repaint` (which is a good thing, or all code you write for Swing components would be filled with `repaint` calls).

Side note: when overriding the `paintComponent` method I would recommended to call `super.paintComponent` as well