# Issues with ActionListener(Java)

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues with ActionListener (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656709/issues-with-actionlistener-java)

I am trying to implement action listener on two buttons in JFrame, but the issue is one of the two button is performing both the functions; but i've not configured it to do so.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyChangingCirlce implements ActionListener {
    JButton colorButton, labelButton;
    JLabel myLabel;
    MyDrawPanel mdp;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyChangingCirlce mcc = new MyChangingCirlce();
        mcc.createFrame();
    } // end of main

    public void createFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
         colorButton = new JButton("Changing Colors");
         labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
        myLabel = new JLabel("I'm a label");
        mdp = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mdp);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, myLabel);
        colorButton.addActionListener(this);
        labelButton.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == colorButton) {
            frame.repaint();
        } else {
            myLabel.setText("That's it");
        }

    }

}
```

My labelButton is performing both the action only 1 time; i.e it changes the color of the circle along with the label text.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue= (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(20,70,100,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You override colorButton and labelButton. So the 'else' is always kicking in. Changing the label will cause a redraw.

change

```
    JButton colorButton = new JButton("Changing Colors");
    JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
```

to

```
    colorButton = new JButton("Changing Colors");
    labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
```

After writing myself a class to test it, I came about with this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Foo implements ActionListener {

    JButton colorButton, labelButton;
    JLabel myLabel;
    JFrame frame;
    MyDrawPanel mdp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo mcc = new Foo();
        mcc.createFrame();
    } //end of main

    public void createFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        colorButton = new JButton("Changing Colors");
        labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
        myLabel = new JLabel("I'm a label");
        mdp = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JSplitPane jsp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        mdp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        jsp.setLeftComponent(mdp);
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 600);
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
        right.add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
        right.add(BorderLayout.WEST, myLabel);
        jsp.setRightComponent(right);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jsp);
        colorButton.addActionListener(this);
        labelButton.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == colorButton) {
            myLabel.setText("Color button's it");
            frame.repaint();
        } else {
            myLabel.setText("That's it" + new Date().toString());
        }

    }

    public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
            g.setColor(randomColor);
            g.fillOval(20, 70, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the Buttons(as suggested by you), but why would changing the label would cause the frame to repaint; i am not calling the repaint method here.

Comment: @Ankit from your description on what happens I just assume that changing the label causes the frame to be repainted. That is your `if` does never ever kick in so something else is causing the repaint. You might want to trigger the color calculation by a separate method that you call exactly when you want to change the color (and not just on a repaint)

Comment: @Ankit after changing the Buttons, does the label change work?

Comment: @Ankit If you run into such problems again I suggest you use actions that are better predictable then color changes (like a System.out.println("something"); or a label change).

Comment: i tried using three word label(before change and after change; so that they consume the same space on the pane), things seems fine to me. Colors are not changing now.

Comment: @Ankit Colors not changing now is strange. I tested it and found that when the text changes the circle is moved (and therefore repainted). I tested it with a JSplitPane (so the label won't interfere with the circle) and now the Color button triggers the circle and the label button triggers the label. So after the change I suggested it worked as expected, although thats most likely not what you wanted. I'll post my code in my answer.

Comment: in my previous post; i said color aren't changing now; it meant that the colors are not changing after i click 'labelButton'(only label is changing); the color is changing only if I click the changeColor button.   I think the reason why the color of the circle/Oval changed previously was because the circle was moving(you also noticed the same).

Comment: @Ankit Very well, so then everything is correct now? Then please mark the answer as correct (the hook left of the answer, below the votes)

Comment: could you please share you're code that is JSplitPane.

Comment: @Ankit I don't understand. The JSplitPane is just for reference and not an important part. Also its part of Java Swing (classpath is: javax.swing.JSplitPane ). You will find the code online if you need it.